# What were the Ringwraiths before becoming that?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

The Ringwraiths were kings, sorcerers and other powerful sorts, according to Galadriel. Do we know who they used to be, what they ruled, and other details as to the nature of their former identities?

Answer (score 1):

[Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Nazg%C3%BBl) tells us that:

> three of the Nine were lords of Númenor corrupted by Sauron,[1](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Hunt_for_the_Ring) and one was a king among the Easterlings.

Citing '[The Hunt for the Ring](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Hunt_for_the_Ring)' from *The Unfinished Tales*.  Other than that, all we know is they were nine men and each of them was of nobility!

Comment: They were kings, except for you know, those three Numenorean lords.  Unless the running of the Black Numenorean colonies were such that they had kings, of Numenorean descent, that were subject to the Numenorean king, they could not have really been kings.

Comment: @suchiuomizu fair point; I have accordingly rephrased my answer ;)

Comment: Hey, new profile pic!

Answer (score 1):

### They were Men with great power in the mortal world, and Sauron gave them the Nine Rings and bound them to him.

From [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Nazg%C3%BBl) (referenced to the *Silmarillion*, *Unfinished Tales*, and the Appendices to *Lord of the Rings*:

> Sometime during the Second Age (after year S.A. 1600) Sauron gave nine Rings of Power to powerful mortal Men. It is said that **three of the Nine were lords of Númenor corrupted by Sauron, and one was a king among the Easterlings**.
>
> For many years the bearers used the rings to gain great wealth, prestige and power, becoming "mighty in their day, kings, sorcerers, and warriors of old". The effect of the rings caused their lives to be prolonged, and to see things of the Unseen. But over time their bodily forms faded until they became wraiths entirely, slaves under the domination of Sauron's One Ring.
>
> Known as the Nazgûl, they first appeared around S.A. 2251 and were soon established as Sauron's principal servants.